# Stuck on Naive Bayes Classification

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

I'm working on a example understanding Naive Bayes classification, and wondering if my thought process is correct.  So I have three users, and true or false if they own Nike or Reebok shoes, or both.  So users can own more than one pair of shoes.  I want to calculate the probability of Reebok's if they own Nike's.  Here is my data:

```
User  | Nike  | Reebok 
Jesse | true  | false
Jake  | false | true 
John  | true  | true   - only user with both
```

Here is how I'm attempting to do this:

```
1) P(both | Reebok) = 1/2 = 50%  
2) Prior Prob = P(both | total user = 1/3 = 33%  
3) P(Reebok | total user = 2/3 = 67%
4) Posterior Prob = (50% * 33%)/67% = 25%
```

So the result would be if a user owned Nike's, they have a 25% posterior probability of owning Reebok's.

Comment: I don't understand your complicated calcul, but you clearly P(both/just Reebok) should be 0 because you can have "both" if you only have "reebok". If you mean P(both | reebok), then this is 50%, and the same for P(both | nike), so you directly get your answer.

Comment: @ Holt - sorry assumption is that a user can have more than one pair of shoes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math question. It would be more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem):

```
p(Reebok | Nike) = p(Reebok) p(Nike | Reebok) / p(Nike)
```

In your example:

- `p(Reebok) = 2/3`
- `p(Nike) = 2/3`
- `p(Nike | Reebok) = 1/2`

So, the result `p(Reebok | Nike) = 1/2` as expected.

Comment: So I calculated the probability at 25%, but according to your answer it's 50%.  I need to change my logic.  Would Naive Bayes produce a different answer?

Comment: @jKraut No, there is no other answer. You do not have independent variable `Both`. You can verify directly that the correct result is 50%: Jake and John own Nike and only 50% of them own Reebok.

Comment: @jKraut You can play with more interesting cases when `p(Reebok | Nike)` is not equal `p(Nike | Reebok)`, for example you can add 4th user that own only `Reebok`

Comment: @ Orest Hera - thx for clarification.  So would it be correct to call this a Bayes classifier or Naive Bayes classifier?

Comment: @jKraut No, it is just an example of using helper _Bayes' theorem_ for calculating _Conditional probability_ required for _Bayes classification_. Here [Naive Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) you can find example of simple _Gaussian naive Bayes_ for continuous data and its usage below for _Sex classification_ using _height_, _weight_ and _foot size_. Actually the _Naive_ assumption of conditional independence is needed when we have many different variables (input parameters).